# Adding an item to a location in a text based game

Tags: java

I'm currently working on creating a text based game. I'm having trouble adding the user provided item to the location. How can I do this using the code I have now?
Thanks for the help.

```
 public class Location
{

private String localDesc;
private Item localItem;
HashMap<String, Location> nbors = new HashMap<String, Location>();

public Location(String pDesc)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    localDesc = pDesc;
    localItem = null;
}


public Location(String pDesc, Item pItem)
{
    // put your code here
    localDesc = pDesc;
    localItem = pItem;
}


public Item getItem(){
    return localItem; 
}


public String getDescription(){
    return localDesc;
}


 public void addItem(Item i){
    // Need help here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the method like:

```
public void addItem(Item i){
    localItem = i;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was overthinking that.  Thank you!